How can I get SignalR to work with a static Azure Web App which is linked to an API which is an App Service?
In Azure, I have an Angular app hosted as a Static Web App and an API hosted as an App Service which also uses SignalR. Recently, to avoid preflight requests, I used the Static Web App feature to link my SWA to my App Service so I can use a single domain name for both resources. So instead of my SWA (https://www.example.com) calling "https://api.example.com/..." it calls "https://www.example.com/api/..." and Azure sends all "/api" traffic to my App Service. This works great except that I can see in the Dev Tools Console of my browser that SignalR is failing about every 45 seconds.
My guess would be something with the ws:// protocol, but nothing is getting logged, so I can't tell what the problem is. As a workaround, I have SignalR still calling my API directly instead of through the SWA, but if I could avoid preflight requests for SignalR as well, that'd be ideal.
How can I setup my SWA to forward SignalR traffic correctly?
